# Missing Binding on dagger 2 injection

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm getting this error with Dagger 2

C:\Users\Anon\AndroidStudioProjects\BarreChat1082\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debu 
g\com\example\barrechat108\Dependencies\RepositoryComponent.java:8: error: 
[Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.barrechat108.MainActivity cannot be 
provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.

```
public abstract interface RepositoryComponent {
            ^
  com.example.barrechat108.MainActivity is injected at
      com.example.barrechat108.Dependencies.RepositoryComponent.inject(com.example.barrechat108.MainActivity)
```

I thought I had set up the injection correctly,  My modules are

```
@Module
class RepositoryModule {

//Provide singleton instance of our database for use by entire app.
//Set up in application's onCreate method
@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesDatabase(applicationContext: Application) : AppDatabase {
    val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
        applicationContext,
        AppDatabase::class.java, "AppDatabase"
    ).build()
    return db
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesRepository(database: AppDatabase) : Repository {
    val repos = Repository(database)
    return repos
}


}
```

and

```
@Module
class AppModule (application: Application) {

val mApplication = application

@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesApplication() : Application {
    return mApplication
}

}
```

The component used for injection to the MainActivity is

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules=[AppModule::class, RepositoryModule::class])
interface RepositoryComponent{
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

Which is where the error is contained.

To build the instance of Dagger2, I extended from the Application class and in the manifest I told the app to use this code,

```
class BarreApp : Application() {

private lateinit var mRepositoryComponent: RepositoryComponent

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    mRepositoryComponent = DaggerRepositoryComponent.builder()
        .appModule(AppModule(this))
        .repositoryModule(RepositoryModule())
        .build()
}

fun getRepositoryComponent(): RepositoryComponent {
    return mRepositoryComponent
}


}
```

Finally, the activity I use the data injection in is the MainActivity.  In this Main Activity, I create an instance of the Repository and send it to the view model from this start activity.  I get rid of re-assignment by checking whether or not the repository was already set in the viewmodel.  So each time the MainActiviy goes through on create, it opens the viewmodel and checks whether it has a repository and if it doesn't it pulls the repository that was injected on it and puts it into the ViewModel.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var mPager: ViewPager

@Inject
private lateinit var mRepository: Repository

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.barreBar))

    //Get Repository Component using Dagger2
    val mApp = application as BarreApp
    mApp.getRepositoryComponent().inject(this)

    //Get the main ViewModel
    val barreViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BarreViewModel :: class.java)

    //Add repository to ViewModel
    barreViewModel.setRepository(mRepository)

}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same problem